# What mount options are enabled implicitly in read-only mode for ext4

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4

If `ext4` partition is mounted with `ro` option:

```
/dev/sdxY    /    ext4    ro    0    1
```

are any additional options enabled implicitly too?

For instance, is any of the following options (which can affect on performance) enabled:
- `noatime`;
- `barrier`;
- `data=writeback`;
- `nobh`.

Comment: It depends on the kernel version. It's the same for ro and rw mounts.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the corresponding entry in `/proc/mounts`, you will get the whole list of options added implicitly at mount time.

Comment: I've explored `/proc/self/mount*` and I didn't see that such options was enabled. But how can work `atime` in read-only mode? Or what is the purpose of `barrier=1` (which is enabled by default on `ext4`) in read-only mode?

Comment: @Gluttton Write-mode options like `atime` or `barrier` have no effect on a read-only mount. But they will take effect as soon as you switch to read-write mode (`mount -o remount,rw`)